# Ckeditor error when in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ckeditor

I want to use ckeditor in bootstrap modal, but when I try to use it doesn't work. If click any icons, it gives an error in console like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined` and I cannot write anything in it. But I can use it on the page well.

```
<script src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>


<div id="detail" class="modal fade form"  tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"  data-width="800">
  <div class="modal-body">
 <textarea rows="2" class="ckeditor form-control input-inline input-medium " name="note"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31883072/1883256).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add jquery js script and put it in the front of other js scripts,such as

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
```

Comment: I have all of them I just shared some part of codes, otherwise it did not work on the page, but works. juat forgot to delete validate.js

Comment: I think this is extremely unlikely to be the cause as CKEditor does not require jquery in any way.